# Composer подключение всех классов со всех директорий

Tags: php, классы, composer, autoload

Сейчас для автозагрузки классов мне приходится в composer.json прописывать в автозагрузку название каждого пространства имен и директории для них.

Можно ли в composer.json сделать так чтобы он загружать все классы со всех имеющих директорий проекта?

Comment: Можно. Читайте про PSR стандарты для автозагрузки.

Comment: Если пространства имен у вас соответствуют структуре директорий, в котороом расположены файлы - используйте автозагручик `psr-4`. Если нет - `classmap`